# How to get the whole query string using BaseX RESTXQ?

Tags: rest, query-string, basex

I'm using a BaseX RESTXQ `.xqm` script to get an HTTP query parameter `price` from a URI, eg;

```
URI:    /foo/?price=20
Result: <price>20</price>
```

This is the `.xqm` code;

```
declare
  %rest:path("foo")
  %rest:query-param("price", "{$price}")
  function page:foo($price) {
    <price>{$price}</price>
  };
```

However, how can I get the whole query? Eg;

```
URI:     /foo/?hello=world&this=that&foo=bar
Result:  <query>hello=world&this=that&foo=bar</query>
```

My problem is that I don't know how many params the query will have or what those params might be called. There might be any number of params (zero to n) and they might be called anything at all. Being able to get the whole query as a single string would solve my problem.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current RESTXQ draft provides no solution for dynamically requesting query parameters.

In the related JAX-RS specification, several `Context` annotations exist to make additional request information available to a Java function (see an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example)). Newer versions of BaseX will provide a [Request Module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Request_Module), which could be extended to provide dynamical access to all query parameters. You may want to write to the [basex-talk](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk) mailing list or to Adam Retter (the inventor of RESTXQ) to further motivate such an extension.